# Codeigniter dropdown values are not shown

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Codeigniter
I'm using a  drop down and 
My problem is that i'm not getting the value from the database

Here is my code

Table Fields:

id, name,category_online

Model code - category_model.php

```
<?PHP   
   class category_model extends CI_Model{
       public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    }
public function get_all_online_select() {
        $this->db->select('id, name'); //change this to the two main values you want to use
        $this->db->from('category');
        $this->db->where('category_online', 1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
            $data[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
        }
        return $query->result_array();
}
}
?>
```

Here is my Controller -Welcome.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    }
function add_content() {
        $data = array();
       $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('category_model');
        $data['select_options'] = $this->category_model->get_all_online_select();
        $this->load->view('add_content', $data);
}
}
```

Here is my view-add_content.php

```
<?php
   echo form_open('save_content');
   echo form_fieldset();
   echo form_dropdown('categories', $select_options);
   echo form_submit('category_submit', 'Submit');
   echo form_fieldset_close();
   echo form_close();
?>
```

This is what the out put looks like

http://jsbin.com/ecuzil/2/edit

No values from the database are being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return **$data** from the model file like

```
public function get_all_online_select() {
    $this->db->select('id, name'); //change this to the two main values you want to use
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->where('category_online', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = array();
    $my_data = $query->result_array();
    foreach($my_data as $row){
        $data[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
    }
    return $data;
 }
```

Comment: Now the error is
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/category_model.php

Line Number: 14
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: then define the $data as array in model file

Comment: I changed the return $query->result_array(); to $data ..Now I am getting that error

Comment: note that, `$data` should be processed in controller not in model (explicitly I mean `foreach` loop).